# How to pass PHP variable into Function

Tags: php, variables

I am modifying my Wordpress loop so it only shows posts that were published after the current logged in user was registered. To get the date the user registered I am using the following successfully -

```
<?php $regdate = date("Y-d-m", strtotime(get_userdata(get_current_user_id( ))->user_registered)); ?>
```

To modify the loop I am using the below successfully -

```
    <?php
      function filter_where($where = '') {
      $where .= " AND post_date >= '2010-02-18'";
      return $where;
      }
      add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
      query_posts($query_string);
    ?>
```

What I need help with is passing the $regdate variable in place of the text date '2010-02-18'. I've tried a few variations but it breaks. I'm sure this is quite simple for anyone PHP savvy... please help!

Comment: Did you try the **global** keyword for your variable ?

Comment: Change the function to `function filter_where($where, $my_date) {` and call it with function `filter_where('', $regdate) {` with this instead of the text  `$where .= " AND post_date >= $my_date";`

Comment: Sorry Steve, I'm a little confused by your answer, would you mind an example?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you could do this in two different basic ways: $GLOBALS and passing function arguments.

**$GLOBALS**

> An associative array containing references to all variables which are
>   currently defined in the global scope of the script. The variable
>   names are the keys of the array.

```
function boo(){
    echo $GLOBALS['foo'];
}
$foo = 'bar';
boo(); // output: bar
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

**Function arguments**

> Information may be passed to functions via the argument list, which is
>   a comma-delimited list of expressions. The arguments are evaluated
>   from left to right.

```
function boo($foo){
    echo $foo;
}
boo('bar'); // output: bar
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Just FYI: I've been told your second solution is better practice than the first. The use of 'custom' global vars is discouraged.

Comment: And why is that discouraged? @dn Fer

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why To be clear... I'm not saying it's wrong to use them, I'm saying you might want to avoid it.

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you able to give me an example of how I would use this in my code please?

Comment: The examples are in my answer, copy the code and see for yourself.